# Eager Loading First Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Story` model and a `Post` model.  Each story has many posts, and each post belongs to a story.

When I load a specific story into memory from the DB I want to eager load that story's most recent post.  Here's how I do it now:

```
@story = Story.includes(:posts).find(params[:story_id])
@latest_post = @story.posts.first  #Note, story.posts :order => "created_at DESC"
```

This works, but it doesn't seem very effecient to load all of a story's posts into memory when I only need the most recent post.  Is there a way to limit the `includes` to only eagerly load the first post?  Should I even be worrying about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL `order by`, `join` and `limit`. An `ActiveRecord` query would look like this:

```
@latest_post = @story.include(:posts).order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

This will create a join with posts, order by newest posts and just fetch one.

Comment: don't think that this works.  `NoMethodError: undefined method `includes` for `#<Story:0x007fd14652d8d8>`. Aren't you trying to apply `includes` etc. to a Story instance?

Comment: Ops, typo, it is `include`.